# Ошибка: Should never call 'set' on setterless property

Tags: java, jackson

Получил ошибку, когда мытался десериализовать ответ в Jackson

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of org.proj.model.profile.Profile, problem: Should never call 'set' on setterless property
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@2d881384; line: 10, column: 1] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.proj.model.profile.Profile, problem: Should never call 'set' on setterless property
at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@2d881384; line: 10, column: 1] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:200)
```

В этом месте, я добавил в конструктор Profile еще одну переменную

```
@JsonProperty("childrens") List<String> childrens
```

и появилась ошибка после вызова:

```
return restClient.exchange(PROFILES_URL + "/name" + path, HttpMethod.GET, restClient.makeHttpEntityWithAuth(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<Collection<Profile>>() {
            });
```

Искал в иентернете по названию ошибки, не нашел.

Класс Profile:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Profile{

private final String id;
private final List<String> childrens;

public Profile(
        @JsonProperty("id") String id,
        @JsonProperty("childrens") List<String> childrens) {
    this.id = id;
    this.childrens = childrens;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public List<String> getChildrens() {
    return childrens;
}
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Выложите код класса Profile. У вас конструктор помечен аннотацией `@JsonCreator`?

Comment: @Uraty добавил класс в описании проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли про `@JsonCreator` у конструктора. Поэтому Jackson и пытается использовать Setter вместо constructor, а setter'а у вас как раз и нет.

```
@JsonCreator //here
public Profile(
         @JsonProperty("id") String id,
         @JsonProperty("childrens") List<String> childrens) {
     this.id = id;
     this.childrens = childrens;
}
```

[Вот еще немного по теме](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_409.html)

Comment: А почему раньше работало все, был только один id, без JsonCreator?

Comment: Не помогло. Та же ошибка

Comment: Может приходят значения, которые конструктор распарсить не может?